# Move an element when page is scrolled

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to control various div elements upon page scroll, similar to [lamoulade.com](http://lamoulade.com).

I want a 300px X 300px div to move from left to right when I scroll down, and from right to left when I scroll up.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you aren't interested in the technical fundamentals of how such animations work, you might find this article informative: [Guide to Scrolling Animation Libraries](https://ihatetomatoes.net/guide-scrolling-animation-libraries/). Check out the [Jarallax](http://www.jarallax.com/demo/) or [Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) libraries, among others.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way out without including libraries other than JQuery.

Comment: Yes, but how its coded depends on what specifically you want to happen. You might check out the source code of the site you linked. Building such a system from scratch can get fairly complex, but I respect your enthusiasm if you're looking to learn how.

Comment: I don't want that complex div animations in my project. All I need is a 300X300 div moving from left to right when I scroll down, and from right to left when I scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });
}
```

Here's a common example that makes a scroll to top button appear when a page has been scrolled a little. You can use the same technique to make other changes to the DOM / animation on certain screen scroll points.

Comment: Yeah it helped a little. But it wouldn't work when I scroll back up after scrolling down once. One way out may be by creating a function that checks the current scrollTop value and accordingly places the all the div elements, but that will be too tedious.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial to build something more sophisticated http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/05/lateral-on-scroll-sliding-with-jquery/